# Where can I find the Qiskit tutorial as a pdf?

Tags: qiskit, resource-request

A documentation of Qiskit language is provided on [qiskit.org/documentation/](https://qiskit.org/documentation/). However, this is an on-line source and sometimes I would apprecite to have an off-line version at hand.

**My questions are:**

1. Is it possible to download the documentation I mentioned above in PDF? Or is it available somewhere?
2. Could you please recommend me any other Qiskit textbook for beginers in Qiskit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Qiskit documentation is included in the [Qiskit Github repositories](https://github.com/Qiskit), so if you clone the Qiskit repositories locally, you'll have full access to the documentation offline.  Alternatively, you could use something like [HTTrack](https://www.httrack.com/) to download and access the documentation website offline.

The [Qiskit textbook](https://qiskit.org/textbook/preface.html) is probably the best resource for learning Qiskit.  There is also a nice set of Qiskit tutorials [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.04359), and the documentation itself includes a set of [tutorials](https://qiskit.org/documentation/tutorials/circuits/1_getting_started_with_qiskit.html).